# Print the selected value in the TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created an `ActionSheet`, but was unable to print the value I selected on the `TextField`.

I do not know how to do it. I will be glad if you can help.

```
struct illedetayyip: View {
    @State private var iliskiDurumlari: [String] = ["Evli", "Bekar", "Ayrı", "anan"]
    @State private var iliskiArray = NSMutableArray()
    @State private var iliskiVisible = false
    @State private var iliski = ""

    func iliskiFunc() {
        for i in 0 ..< self.iliskiDurumlari.count {
            let button: ActionSheet.Button = .default(Text(self.iliskiDurumlari[i]), action: {
                print(self.iliskiDurumlari[i])
            })
            self.iliskiArray[i] = button
        }
    }

    init() {
        iliskiFunc()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("İlişki Durumu Seçiniz..", text: $iliski)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).stroke(Color(red: 45 / 255,
                                                                         green: 0 / 255, blue: 112 / 255), lineWidth: 1))
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $iliskiVisible) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text("Bir İlişki Durumu Seçiniz"), message:
                        Text("Aşagıda"), buttons: self.iliskiArray as! [ActionSheet.Button])
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.iliskiVisible.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `NSMutableArray` and then cast it back to `[ActionSheet.Button]`.

Try this instead:

```
struct illedetayyip: View {
    @State private var iliskiDurumlari: [String] = ["Evli", "Bekar", "Ayrı", "anan"]
    @State private var iliskiVisible = false
    @State private var iliski = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("İlişki Durumu Seçiniz..", text: $iliski)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(Color(red: 45 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 112 / 255), lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $iliskiVisible, content: actionSheet)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.iliskiVisible.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Bir İlişki Durumu Seçiniz"),
            message: Text("Aşagıda"),
            buttons: iliskiDurumlari.map { value in
                ActionSheet.Button.default(Text(value), action: {
                    self.iliski = value
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't run it. Can you edit and show this in the codes I posted? @pawello2222

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood, I wanted to print the selected value in the text field.

Comment: @metaflor22 If you have a new question please create a new post. I'll try to help you there.

Comment: I added a new post @pawello2222